Cannot access file using fetch api, 403 forbidden error
I have created an ec2 windows instance where I have installed IIS. I have created a Cloudflare worker to download files using fetch api. But when I use await fetch('http://54.235.2.69/a.pdf', {cf:{cacheEverything: true}}), I'm getting 403 forbidden error. I'm able to download file directly using the server link but not using fetch api.
Direct Server link for sample pdf
Cloudflare worker link to download sample pdf
I have enable directory browsing and added mime type. Also checked the website folder have permissions to IUSR.

There are many reasons for this error, you need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 403 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

I solved this by binding a domain name. Instead of using ip address, now I use domain name and it is solved.
